# how to change the color of multi color glyphicons (icon font)

Tags: css, glyphicons

I try to change the color of a multicolor glyphicon when the user hover.

This is my example:

https://jsfiddle.net/p7ht5kzh/

I try it with this code:

```
.icon-usp_emblemservice:hover{
  color: red;
}
```

But it doesn't work with multicolor icons.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**try this**

```
span.icon-usp_emblemservice:hover>span:before {
    color: red;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/p7ht5kzh/1/)

Comment: Thank you, works fine. I will mark this answer as correct.

Comment: Glad to help you:)